# send a broadcast from logcat

Tags: android, logcat, broadcast

how can i send broadcast from logcat result like send broadcast if activity start (it taged with activity manager)

like if browser start the logcat will display that :

```
09-10 09:47:04.020: I/ActivityManager(2707): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 2880
```

there are app in market do like what is ask for which called

LogCatNotifier

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=RabiSoft.LogCatNotifier&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is how do you know when to send a broadcast when something specific is logged, you should have a `Service` monitor the device's logs, and when it encounters a log that you want to send a broadcast about, then you should send a broadcast.

You can learn about reading from logs programmatically [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically)

**EDIT:** If I'm not mistaken, in JellyBean it's no longer possible to read logs from any app besides your own.

Comment: if i put a service monitor the logcat i think it will drain the battery because the result from logcat is about 10 result per second so i should put at timer catch every result ( every 100 mils seconds)  
but , thank you for the link is very useful .. 
i read from comments there are handler for logging

thank you again