# Get crash exception message to store into database

Tags: java, android, logging, exception

I am writing my own logger that stores all the entries into a SQLite database using Sugar ORM. I can do normal log.e, log.d, log.i just fine, but in the event the app crashes I want my logger to be able to get the exception message and store it into the SQLite.

How would I get the exception message so I can store it into my SQLite database before the app crashes?

Thanks!

Comment: Would the solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346866/send-a-broadcast-from-logcat solve your problem?

Comment: "in the event the app crashes I want my logger to be able to..." --> why isn't your priority to prevent app crashes instead of saving logs ?

Comment: @2dee obviously I want to prevent crashing, but I want my custom logger to be able to log crashes just like how regular loggers are able to do. I would think even if you try to make your app as bullet proof as possible, full featured logging should be implemented regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Use try-catch and all other exceptions you can log like this example shows:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            _logger.logUncaughtException(e);
        }

    });
```

Comment: can this be added to a logging library? So when you are setting the uncaughtexception, it would call the listener in a library?

Comment: @Alan it is static call, so you can do it everywhere.